# Why is scope variable in directive undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following parent and child (http://jsfiddle.net/j1ee5zss/2/):

```
<div parent parent-model="my-model">
  <div child>Child</div>
</div>
```

In child directive I am trying to get parent-model, e.g., "my-model":

```
app.directive("parent", parent);

function parent() {

  var parent = {
    controller: ["$scope", controller],
    replace: false,      
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      model: "="
    }    
  };

  return parent;

  function controller($scope) { 
    this.getModel = function () {
      return $scope.model;
    }    
  }   
}  

app.directive("child", child);

function child() {
  var child = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    require: "^parent",
    restrict: "A"
  };
  return child;
  function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {    
    var model = controller.getModel();
    console.log(model);    
  }  
}
```

Why is model undefined when I write console.log(model)?

Comment: Doesn't seem to return undefined in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: indeed, it shows `model` in the console (chrome/mac latest)

Comment: sorry, wrong fiddle ... can you please check the new one? just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should observe parentModel, but not model?

```
      scope: {
           parentModel: "="
       }
```

Or just use attribute model.

Comment: Have you also changed 
 function controller($scope) { 
    this.getModel = function () {
      return $scope.parentModel;
    }    
  }

Comment: Yes, but now I get 0 instead of "my-model" ... Have no idea why. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3s8q2f9/

Comment: try pass json object or number. And write in log - JSON object. We always bind json objects)) Sometimes strings (when you need bind string use "@", but not "=").
Directives used in some controller. So you bind object from this controller to directive (scope. test = { qwe: "qwe"}) and bind (parent-model="test")

But in your example we should pass pure json object: {testJSON:"testJSON"}

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c3s8q2f9/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the string `my-model`, it needs to be enclosed in quotes.

```
<div parent parent-model="'my-model'">
  <div child>Child</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
scope: {
    model: "=parentModel"
}
```

When you bind an attribute to scope with bi-directional binding, `=`, the attribute gets evaluated as an Angular expression, not as a literal.

Comment: is there a way to obtain my-model string on child directive without using ''?

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly doing two-way binding. You are creating isolated-scope naming 'model' $scope variable, so this is how you can get value of parent attribute e.g. parent-model.

`scope: {
    model: "=parentModel"
}`

Provided you are having my-model value in your controller.